# Copying ranges with varying rows using a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to vba coding and I need it for worksheet with 17520 rows of data. I need to copy and paste 12 times, each with 1460 rows of data to another work sheet to run solver then paste the results from the solver back to the worksheet with data. I have wrote vba code 12 times with the same command (shown below is just 2 times). Now I was thinking of using the looping method to summarize this long code and I do not know how to start. Could anyone help me with this?

```
Sub RunModel()

Dim Data As Worksheet
Dim Model As Worksheet
Set Data = Sheets("Customer 1 (A)")
Set Model = Sheets("Sheet 1")

'1st month
'Copy Data
Data.Range("D8:E1467").Copy Model.Range("D8")
Data.Range("L8:L1467").Copy Model.Range("L8")
Data.Range("I7").Copy
Model.Range("I7").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

'Run OpenSolver
Result = RunOpenSolver(False, True)

'Paste result and datas back to Data
Model.Range("N4").Copy
Data.Range("Q7").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
Model.Range("F8:O1467").Copy Data.Range("F8")



'2nd month
'Copy Data
Data.Range("D1468:E2927").Copy Model.Range("D8")
Data.Range("L1468:L2927").Copy Model.Range("L8")
Data.Range("I1467").Copy
Model.Range("I7").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)


'Run OpenSolver
Result = RunOpenSolver(False, True)

'Paste result and datas back to Data
Model.Range("N4").Copy
Data.Range("Q8").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
Model.Range("F8:O1467").Copy Data.Range("F1468")
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Jeeped's answer. Same concept (using a `For .. Next`) but slightly different code.

```
dim i as long
dim rowOffset as long
const rowLength as Long = 1460 ' magic number
const startRow as long = 8 ' magic number
    for i= 1 to 12   ' note, standard step of 1
        rowOffset = (i - 1) * rowLength + startRow
        Data.Range(Data.Cells(4, rowOffset), Data.Cells(4,rowOffset + rowLength -1)).Copy Model.Range("D8")
        Data.Range(Data.Cells(12, rowOffset), Data.Cells(12,rowOffset + rowLength -1).Copy Model.Range("L8")  'Why copy over same cell?
        rowOffset = (i - 1) * rowLength
        Model.Range("I7") = Data.Range("I7").offset(rowOffset, 0).value

        'Run OpenSolver
        Result = RunOpenSolver(False, True)

        'Paste result and datas back to Data
        Data.Range("Q7").offset(i, 0) = Model.Range("N4").value
        rowOffset = (i - 1) * rowLength
        Model.Range("F8:O1467").Copy Data.Range("F8").offset(rowOffset, 0)

    next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a For ... Next with a non-default step.

```
dim i as long

for i=1 to 17520 step 1460
    Data.Range("D8:E1467").offset(i-1, 0).Copy Model.Range("D8")
    Data.Range("L8:L1467").offset(i-1, 0).Copy Model.Range("L8")
    Model.Range("I7") = Data.Range("I7").offset(i-1, 0).value

    'Run OpenSolver
    Result = RunOpenSolver(False, True)

    'Paste result and datas back to Data
    Data.Range("Q7").offset(i\1460, 0) = Model.Range("N4").value
    Model.Range("F8:O1467").Copy Data.Range("F8").offset(i-1, 0)

next i
```